# Why can we write a differential as a sum of partial derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why is it that if $x=x(y,z)$, we can write the following:

$$dx=\left ( \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right )_zdy+\left ( \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} \right )_ydz$$

I found this is in Concepts in Thermal Physics by Blundell in appendix C.6.

Answer (score 1):

For a differentiable function $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$, writing $f(a+h)=f(a)+df_a(h)+o(h)$ and taking $h=t\cdot v$, with $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $v\in E$, leads to
$$df_a(t\cdot v)=f(a+t\cdot v)-f(a)+o(t\cdot v)$$
$$\implies df_a(v)=\frac{f(a+t\cdot v)-f(a)}{t}+o(v)$$
and thus, taking the limit $t\to 0$,
$$df_a(v)=\partial_{a,v}f,$$
where $\partial_{a,v}f$ is the partial derivative of $f$ at the point $a$ in the direction $v$. Using the linearity of the differential and taking a basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ of $E$, you get
$$df_a(\alpha^1e_1+\dots+\alpha^ne_ n)=\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}\right|_a\alpha^1+\dots+\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}\right|_a\alpha^n,$$
where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}:=\partial_{a,e_i}f$, which is the general case of the formula you are looking for since in shorter notation it will be
$$df_a=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i.$$